# Identifying Path in Matrix Game

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, printing, breadth-first-search

I am returning the length of the shortest path if there's is one. Otherwise, I return -1.

I'm trying to print the matrix in such a way that all visited nodes that were a part of the shortest path are marked with '$' instead of '1'. However, I'm not able to do so.

```
def Path(grid):
    #print(grid)
    start = (0, 0)
    queue = collections.deque([[start]])
    seen = set([start])
    while queue:
        path = queue.popleft()
        x, y = path[-1]
        if y == 7 and x == 7:
            #print(path)
            for (i, j) in path:
                grid[i][j] = '$'
            print(grid)
            return len(path)
        for x2, y2 in ((x + 1, y), (x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x, y - 1):
            if (grid[y2][x2] != 0) and (x2, y2) not in seen:
                queue.append(path + [(x2, y2)])
                seen.add((x2, y2))

    print(grid)    
    return -1
```

Comment: The posted code has no indentation problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in how you address `grid`:

When looking for the next available move, you do this test:

```
grid[y2][x2] != 0
```

where `(x2, y2)` is potentially added to the path.

But when you finally assign the `$`, you write:

```
grid[i][j] = '$'
```

where `(i, j)` is the tuple taken from the path.

This is not consistent. You should swap the coordinate position in one of the two `grid[][]` expressions to make them consistent.

Comment: This fixes the problem in one way. It works if I print ```grid[j][i] = 2``` but gives the ```invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'X'``` error when I try to print ```grid[j][i] = '$'``` How can I fix this when all other values of the grid are 1s and 0s but this one has to be a character?

Comment: But in your question you do `print(grid)`, and that works. It seems you are asking a new question about different code? What do you mean with *"try to print `grid[j][i] = '$'`"*? That is an assignment; not something you print... The error you mention can happen when trying to convert the content to integer, but the code in your question does not do that. So you seem to ask questions about code you have not provided.

Comment: No, I'm printing the grid in 2 different places. One at the end if there's no path. Second after the ```grid[j][i] = '$'``` if there is a path. By writing this statement, I intend to change all the 1s which were a part of the shortest path into '$' and then print the updated grid before returning. But it gives an error since '$' isn't an integer.

Comment: What is the line of code that triggers the error? I'm quite sure that line is not in your question.

Comment: This line: ```grid[j][i] = 'X'``` causes the error but you might not get the error in the first attempt if you're passing a grid matrix which has no path from top to bottom. In that case, it prints the unchanged grid and returns -1

Comment: That line cannot possibly trigger that error (or did you use type hints somewhere?). See it run here: https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/question59480075. It may help if you could provide the definition of `grid` in your question's code. If `grid` is not provided by you, but by a test suite, it may well be a non-standard list that performs type checking, and so you should follow the rules and not assign a non-integer. You can see that the error is about calling `int()`, which your code does not do. So it must be in some other code.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question. I added how I'm using the function in my code.

Comment: What is `np`? Are you using numpy? Then there you have the reason. Numpy arrays are created with the type necessary to hold the initial content. Since the initial content is all numeric, numpy will not allow any other type to be assigned. But this really is becoming a very different question. Use standard lists, and you will not have this problem. The benefit from using numpy is greatly reduced if you start mixing types. Alternatively, use "1" instead of 1 and "0" instead of 0, so that everything is string. Next time you ask a question that relies on numpy, make it clear, and tag with `numpy`

Comment: This also shows that the error you mentioned above was *not* on the line `grid[j][i] = '$'`, but somewhere inside the `numpy` library. It would have been most clarifying if you would have said so.